# Stata error when using wild bootstrap command

Tags: stata

I'm getting an error when I use the following command in Stata:

`wildbootstrap regress y x1, cluster(area) rseed(12345)`

where `y` is my dependent variable, `x1` is a vector of independent variables, and `area` is a variable that I want to cluster for.

I get the following error:

`'' found where ':' expected r(198);`

I know it is a syntax error but I can't seem to figure out what is wrong with my code.

I tried to perform `wildbootstrap` command, my best guess is that I've got the variables misspecified or incorrect data types but I am a bit lost.

Comment: I was able to reproduce using the `auto` data with this code: `wildbootstrap regress price mpg weight`. I am also able to reproduce using exact code of the first example in the helpfile here: https://www.stata.com/manuals/rwildbootstrap.pdf

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "vector of independent variables" as usually `x1` in that context is just a single independent variable.

Answer (score 1):

I have ran into the same problem before using my stata 17 version and figured out that it is a new addition to stata 18. My code ran normally using stata 18.